# Mail Merge - Using Business Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I would like to use Mail Merge alongside Gmail but instead of using my personal email, I would like to use my business email.

Please assist me with this since I want to send bulk emails to my prospective client. Your assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please go through this documentation about creating a mail merge - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/mail-merge